# Building Node.js gives error: Node.js configure error: No acceptable C compiler found

Tags: node.js, compiler-construction, arm, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

While trying to use a Ubuntu 14.04 system to cross compile Node.js v0.10.30 for ARM (Raspberry Pi B), I'm experiencing an error message:

```
Node.js configure error: No acceptable C compiler found!

        Please make sure you have a C compiler installed on your system and/or
        consider adjusting the CC environment variable if you installed
        it in a non-standard prefix.
```

How should I fix this problem and compile node.js successfully?

**Commands used on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 x64 installation:**

```
sudo apt-get install gcc g++ git

git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout v0.10.30-release

export AR=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ar
export CC=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export CXX=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++
export LINK=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++

./configure --without-snapshot --dest-cpu=arm --dest-os=linux
```

Comment: IIRC, you need to have `make` also, according to their documentation: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation. Not sure if compiling for ARM is different.

Comment: How did you install this arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi- toolchain?

Comment: @Tony `make` v3.8.1 is installed.

Comment: @unixsmurf I did not install it. Is it something to be installed?

Comment: @unixsmurf I just tried `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` but that does not seem to work.

Comment: @mscdex I think if I'm compiling for Pi using my Ubuntu Desktop, I need to export those so they will run on the Pi, rather than on my ubuntu dekstop.

Comment: Which aspect does not seem to work? Installation or use? How does it not seem to work? Did you change the commands still in the question above?

Comment: @unixsmurf When I run the `./configure` command above, I get the error `Node.js configure error: No acceptable C compiler found`. If I do not export the `CC`, it cannot run on Arm processors.

Comment: So, did the installation succeed? If so, you should update your variable settings to match the name of the installed cross-compilation toolchain binaries.

Comment: @unixsmurf Which crosscompilers should I use?

Comment: You have told me you attempted to install something. You have still not told me whether that installation succeeded. If it did, I suggest you try to use that one. Of course, raspberry Pi makes it needlessly complicated because people interchangeably use toolchains with incompatible ABIs. It would hence also be useful to know what Linux distribution and potential flavour you are using on the Pi. And do please tell me whether the installation step you have described above in fact succeeded or if it failed.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this error as well after trying to run ./configure in my node directory. Here are the commands I ran to get node working for me on an ubuntu server:

1. cd .. (back to directory where node directory was created)
2. sudo apt-get install build-essential
3. cd node/
4. ./configure
5. make (For relative newbies, like me, this step took awhile to complete, so don't freak out too much if that happens for you)
6. sudo make install

Then try running your node file from it's directory. As a small aside, I also got the following error when doing that:

Error: ENOENT, stat '/home/ubuntu/local'
    at Error (native)

To fix that, I just ran: sudo npm install -g npm

Comment: I guess it should be : sudo apt-get install -g npm

Comment: Thanks for the warning about step 5 taking awhile! Cuz it did and I was alittle scared. :)

Answer (score 1):

Install the build essential using the below commands, these will install gcc as well. It worked for me. Let me know if this works for you.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

I was required to use: `sudo apt-get install npm -g -y` in my WSL, VSCode Windows terminal.